# android: compare date with database

Tags: android, database, datetime

I have difficulties comparing the date from my android os to a date stored in my sqlite database on the phone. The goal is: I would like to select all rows for a date earlier than today.

That's how I get the Date - that park works:

```
  android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
  String datum = df.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date()).toString ();
```

For each row in my database I have stored the date as TEXT. e.g. 2012-01-31 (yyyy-MM-dd).

I thought, I could work with "smaller than" ( < ) operator - that worked on a differt project. But, I don't get the correct dates.

Any ideas? Or - how would you approach that problem?

Thanks in advance!
Marco

Comment: store the date as long, thats better and easier to compare

Comment: Use a date or long data type.

Comment: @Eric I agree that a long format would make more sense, but given the format string he's using, string comparisons should work as well. There's almost certainly something else going on here if they don't appear to do so (for instance, one other person having a similar problem recently had some garbage data in their "timestamp" field).

Comment: I thought of using long, but the data is provided to me in the given format. so I thought it would be easier when the date is stored as text. I'll give it a try anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me.

```
$ sqlite3
sqlite> CREATE TABLE date_test(date DATE);
sqlite> INSERT INTO date_test VALUES('2012-01-01');
sqlite> INSERT INTO date_test VALUES('2012-02-01');
sqlite> INSERT INTO date_test VALUES('2012-03-01');
sqlite> SELECT date FROM date_test WHERE date < '2012-02-15';
2012-01-01
2012-02-01
```

Can you provide specific test data for which the behavior is not what you expect?

Comment: arrrrgh. It didn't make sense - now it does. I had garbage data stored in the db. I populated a new database with only one format, now it works. Thanks for your insight!